# Flink 'timeWindow' operation not generating output for PopularPlacesFromKafka example file

Tags: apache-flink

I'm going through Flink tutorial materials from dataArtisans and for some reason when I get to the sample file [PopularPlacesFromKafka.scala](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_scala/connectors/PopularPlacesFromKafka.scala)
I don't get any output sent to stdout.

```
...
// find popular places
val popularSpots = rides
  // match ride to grid cell and event type (start or end)
  .map(new GridCellMatcher)
  // partition by cell id and event type
  .keyBy( k => k )
  // build sliding window
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(15), Time.minutes(5))
  // count events in window
  .apply{ (key: (Int, Boolean), window, vals, out: Collector[(Int, Long, Boolean, Int)]) =>
    out.collect( (key._1, window.getEnd, key._2, vals.size) )
  }

// print result on stdout
    popularSpots.print()
...
```

I've confirmed that data is being pulled from Kafka ok, and it seems to be something when it attempts to do the 'timeWindow' operation that I get no output.  If I remove the 'timeWindow' operation I can see the 'keyBy' data being output.  Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has this same issue this was my problem.

My kafka topic had multiple partitions, but was producing all of the test data to a single partition (0), once I had >1 Kafka consumers, all of the consumers except for the one assigned to partition 0 aren't receiving any data, and thus not sending any watermarks down the operator chain - that causes the window functions to stop emitting data (that's also why it works fine with ProcessingTime in those situations). Here's a relevant JIRA about it:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5479

Comment: I have the same issue as you,  I have been confused for the whole afternoon！ there are 10 partitions of a topic,  but I push logs to only one for simple test, It does not has any output.  But when I push logs to multi partitions again, It works fine！   thanks for figuring out the issue

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure an appropriate speedup for the source? By default (without a speedup factor), the source emulates the original data, i.e., it emits records at the same rate as they were originally generated. That means it takes 1 minute to produce 1 minute of data.

The window operator aggregates every 5 minutes the last 15 minutes of data. Consequently, it will take 5 minutes until the window operator produces the first result.

If you set the speedup factor to 600, you'll get 10 minutes of data in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are several reasons why a Flink job might not produce any output, but a very common reason has to do with watermarking. Flink's event time clock only advances when the current watermark advances, and so without watermarks, a event time window will never fire.

In the case of the Flink training exercises, the taxi ride sources produce watermarks for you. But now that you are working with a Kafka source instead, you will have to implement a timestamp extractor and watermark generator, and then call `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on your stream (see the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html)). A `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` where the delay matches the delay configured by the job that wrote into Kafka will work well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the same code I'm referencing includes the things you are mentioning and still no output.

Comment: The same problem as @AJC,  when I regenerate logs and push them to multiple partitions, it works fine